# How do I use the Result from a CodeActivty<string> in WF 4.0?

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I've created a custom activity in a .NET 4.0 beta 1 WF project.  It's defined as:

```
public class GetCurrentUserMailAddress : CodeActivity<string>
```

because I've read that this is the most efficient way of returning a single result.

At the end, I set the Result using:

```
context.SetValue(Result, up.EmailAddress);
```

But now I'm struggling to use it in my Workflow.  I want to use the value in my next activity but I can't find it.

How do I reference the Result from one custom activity in the next activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind.  I was being thick.  Just in case anyone else is struggling, the Properties window for the custom activity contains a Result property.  Stick your variable name in there and it will be populated with the value of your Result OutArgument.